# Часть иконок из Vue Material VueJS не работает

Tags: vue.js, icon

При попытке использовать иконки из официально предоставленного библиотекой шрифта часть из этих иконок не работает.
Используемая либа [Vue Material](https://www.creative-tim.com/vuematerial/components/icon),
Используемые иконки [Google Material Icons](https://fonts.google.com/icons?selected=Material%20Icons:logout:)
Подключение иконок и либы:

> import 'material-icons-font/material-icons-font.css'
>  import
> 'vue-material/dist/vue-material.min.css'
>  import
> 'vue-material/dist/theme/default.css'

Часть проблемных иконок:

> room_preferences
>  app_registration
>  account_tree
>  logout

Вид присваивания иконок: `md-icon="logout">`

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что была установлена устаревшая версия пакета иконок. Для исправления этого необходимо удалить старый пакет

> npm uninstal package_name

и установить необходимую, в моем случае последнюю стабильную.

> npm install package_name --save